# Simple chain rule application $y = (1-x^{-1})^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am not sure what is going wrong here. I have been doing other applications of the chain rule to cross check that I understand it properly ,but I still do not get a correct answer on this problem while I do on all others.

$$y = (1-x^{-1})^{-1}$$

$$y' = -(1-x^{-1})^{-2} \cdot x^{-2}$$

This is wrong and it  gives a wrong answer, according to wolfram and my book the answer should just be the first part which breaks the chain rule and I do understand why this is acceptable in this specific case but no others.

Comment: Look more closely at what Alpha gives you back - it's not _quite_ the first half of what you've written.  What you've written is actually correct, but try expanding out the result and you may see where Alpha is coming from.

Comment: I have several times with no luck.

Comment: $$-(1-x^{-1})^{-2}x^{-2}=\frac{-1}{x^2(1-x^{-1})^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2\left(1-\frac1x\right)^2}=\frac{-1}{\left(x\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)^2}=\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why did the x^2 turn into just an x in the third step?

Comment: I don't know how you knew to use those specific and very odd manipulations but I did something more intuitive and it just doesn't work. I took $(x^{-1} - 1$ and squared it getting $x^{-2} - 2x^{-1} + 1$ which is very bad and wrong. I then multiply that by $x^2$ and get $(1-2x+x^2)^{-1}$

Comment: At the third step I simply used the fact that $a^2b^2=(ab)^2$. If you think that those manipulations are odd, I’m afraid that you’re likely to have quite a bit of trouble: they are very natural, very standard manipulations. There’s nothing wrong with $x^{-2}-2x^{-1}+1$: it **is** the square of $x^{-1}-1$. And when you multiply by $x^2$ you get $1-2x+x^2=(x-1)^2$; since it’s actually in the denominator, and you also have a minus sign, you’re getting exactly what I got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You applied the chain rule correctly, and obtained "a" correct answer; the discrepancy you find is "simply" due to the fact that your answer  can be simplified. (No pun intended!)

Expanding *your correct* result: $\;\;y' = -(1-x^{-1})^{-2}x^{-2};\;$ we simplify as follows: $$=\frac{-1}{x^2(1-x^{-1})^2}\tag{1}$$
$$=\frac{-1}{x^2\left(1-\frac1x‌​\right)^2}\tag{2}$$ 
$$=\frac{-1}{\left(x\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)^2}\tag{3}$$ $$=\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2}\tag{4}$$  $$= -(x-1)^{-2}\tag{5}$$

So your computation/answer is equivalent to $(5)$.

---

Note: $(2) \to (3)\;\;$ uses the fact that $\;x^ny^n = (xy)^n,\;\text{so}\; (2)$ is equivalent to $(3)$

Answer (score 1):

There is a neater way of handling this. Denote $\log f(x)=Lf(x)$.

$$
f(x)=\bigg(1-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^{-1}\\
Lf(x)=- \log \bigg(1-\frac{1}{x}\bigg)=\log x -\log (x-1)\\
L'f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}=-\frac{1}{x(x-1)}\\
f'(x)=-\frac{f(x)}{x(x-1)}=-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}
$$

EDIT: here I used the following properties of logarithm function:
$$
\log \frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\log f(x)-\log h(x)\\
 \textbf{ If } g(x)=\log f(x) \textbf{ then } \\
g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \Leftrightarrow \\
f'(x)=f(x)g'(x)
$$

Comment: I have no idea why you introduced logs into this, what L means, what L! is or really anything that you did. It might be neater but I don't think it is anything we were ever taught.

Comment: Pls see edits above

Comment: I really can't decipher what you wrote at all. I think you wrote teh chain rule out maybe and you are saying that you took the logs of both sides but I am not sure when or how they went away.

Comment: I didn't use Chain rule here because it is not the only way of solving this problem. Yes, I took logs of both sides and then differentiated the function:$(\log x)'_{x}=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: I am not familiar with that at all don't you have to raise everything to e or something like that to get rid of log?

Comment: $L$ is defined in the first line of my answer. You do not need to 'get rid of log' by exponentiation. See the definition and differentiation of $g(x)$ in the edit.

Comment: I thought that was an equation you were setting up. What happens in the second step? I don't understand where the logx and log x -1 come from.

Comment: Are you familiar with differentiation of logarithm function? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28x%29%27

Comment: I am not smart and I am incredibly bad at math and I lost my sheet with all the derivatives I need to memorize on it so I forgot them all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're right. You just expressed it a little diffently. Remember that $a^xb^x=(ab)^x$

$-(1-x^{-1})^{-2}x^{-2}=-((1-x^{-1})x)^{-2}=-(x-1)^{-2}=-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x)=u^{-1}$ wherein $u=1-\frac{1}{x}$. So according to chain rule we have: $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=\frac{df}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}$$ Here, $$\frac{df}{du}=-1\times u^{-1-1}=-u^{-2}$$ and $$\frac{du}{dx}=-(x^{-1})'=x^{-2}$$ So you have your answer.